# What to do when delete data option doesn't work?

Tags: boot, tablet, huawei

I wanted to know if I can fix my Huawei tablet. It stopped suddenly and it didn't boot up normally. I forced it to boot by holding the <kbd>power</kbd> button and now it got stuck at Android logo. I tried wiping data but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You tagged the question with *rooting* yet you don't mention it in the question at all. Did you try to root the tablet and did the tablet broke down after that?

Comment: "*it didn't boot up normally*" -- so in what other way was it booting? Did it boot only into a screen with an  Android and exclamation mark? Consider explaining the situation from the beginning. For example, tell us what were you doing when the phone suddenly stopped? After that, if it didn't boot straight into Android OS, then what did it do after long-pressing the power button? After wiping data and after seeing the logo, how long did you wait? After a reset, It takes few minutes sometimes to have the device ready to use.